# How can I write greek charakters with Php into a csv-file

Tags: php, csv, character-encoding

How can I write greek charakters with Php into a csv-file
esp. mikro

eg:
fwrite($myFile,$key . ";" . str_replace("μ","%CE%BC",$value) .chr(13).chr(10));

Comment: What is it the encoding of $key? What is it the encoding of your source? ["μ" in your source may already by UTF-8]. Try to use UTF-8 as much as possible (source, web server, etc.), but if you cannot, try to convert other files to UTF-8 as soon as possible (with iconv), and for the output, as late as possible (just to get the smallest surface possible in non UTF-8. Web (and most of the world) is UTF-8 since years

Comment: Please  [edit] your question to share a [mcve]. BTW, there are two different characters with the same glyph: `µ` {U+00B5, 0xC2,0xB5} _Micro Sign_ and another `μ` {U+03BC, 0xCE,0xBC} _Greek Small Letter Mu_…

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.